# Apex Chart - display date in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, apexcharts

Using Apex Charts, how can I display the date of the current highlighted bar in a custom tooltip? For example in this screenshot, I want to display "Jun 2020" instead of the hardcoded "Month" string. So i'm looking for the X axis categories labels, but I don't understand how to display it in the tooltip.

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Month',
    data: [<?= $data ?>]
  }],          
  xaxis: {
    categories: [<?= $labels ?>],
    labels: {
      rotateAlways: true,
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    y: {
      formatter: function (val) {
        return val + " products sold"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: did you try to do this 
`tooltip: {
          x: {
            show: true,
            format: 'dd MMM hh:mm:ss',
          },
        },`

Comment: It's not working, and I also need to display the value (X products sold) together with the date

Answer (score 0):

Test this, add these tootltip parameters in your option

```
options: {
        tooltip: {
        x: {
            format: "dd MMM yyyy",
            formatter: function(value, { series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
            return new Date(value)
                }
            }
    }
```

OR

Use this for date format:

```
options: {
    tooltip: {
    x: {
        format: "MMM yyyy"
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me .
*dont forget use moment library too

```
...tooltip.x.formatter =function(value,{ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w })
{
   return moment(new Date(tooltip_manual_set[value-1])).format('M/D HH:mm');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
tooltip: {
        x: {
            show: true,
            format: "dd MMM yyyy",
            formatter: function (value,{ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
                    return new Date(value).toDateString();
                },
            },
          },
```

[image: Your tooltip should look something like this]